# Uglify Js Creating forloop bug

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have this loop which is uglified and

```
for (var row = 0; row < dbRows.length; row++) {

                         dbRows[row].daysList[day].taskid = dbRows[row].taskid;
                         dbRows[row].daysList[day].activityid = dbRows[row].activityid;
                     }
                 }
             }
```

After uglification it becomes this

```
for (var h = 0; h < b.length; h++)
                        b[h].daysList[g].taskid = b[h].taskid,
                        b[h].daysList[g].activityid = b[h].activityid,
```

so only first line after loop start is executing the other is not working at all.

Comment: are you sure? I'm pretty certain that both lines are one statement because of the commas at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are wrong. The comma operator can be used to put multiple expressions into one expression.

For reference you can look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) page.

Also, here's an example for you to try out:

```js
    for(var h = 0; h<2;h++)
        alert("first line"),
        alert("second line");
```